# GSM 7-bit encoding with 1 bit padding

Tags: php, binary, decimal

The octets from "Hello world" are: `E8 32 9B FD 06 DD DF 72 36 19`

And if apply padding it will become : `D0 65 36 FB 0D BA BF E5 6C 32`

(copy from wiki)

Can I know what's the formula to encoding with 1-bit padding?

Here is the formula of convert string to PDU that I edited :(thanks to source provider)
*The whole complete formula is kinda long so I just post a part of it here...

```
    maxkeys = 160;

    function binToInt(x)//sp
   {
var total = 0;  
var power = parseInt(x.length)-0;   

for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{
    if(x.charAt(i) == '1')
    {
     total = total +Math.pow(2,power);
    }
    power --;
}
return total;
  }

  function intToHex(i) //sp
    {
     var sHex = "0123456789ABCDEF"; 
     h = ""; 
     i = parseInt(i);   
    for(j = 0; j <= 3; j++)
     {
      h += sHex.charAt((i >> (j * 8 + 4)) & 0x0F) +
        sHex.charAt((i >> (j * 8)) & 0x0F);
      }
    return h.substring(0,2);
   }


 function stringToPDU(inpString,size) 
     {

var bitSize = size[0].value * size[0].checked | size[1].value * size[1].checked | size[2].value * size[2].checked;

var octetFirst = "";
var octetSecond = ""; 
var output = "";

var DATA_ENCODING = "00"; 

var VALID_PERIOD = "AA";

var userDataSize;
if (bitSize == 7)
{

    userDataSize = intToHex(inpString.length);

    for(var i=0;i<=inpString.length;i++)
    {
        if(i==inpString.length)
        {
            if (octetSecond != "") // AJA Fix overshoot
            {
                output = output + "" + (intToHex(binToInt(octetSecond)));
            }
            break;
        }
        var current = intToBin(getSevenBit(inpString.charAt(i)),7);

        var currentOctet;
        if(i!=0 && i%8!=0)
        {
            octetFirst = current.substring(7-(i)%8);
            currentOctet = octetFirst + octetSecond;    

            output = output + "" + (intToHex(binToInt(currentOctet)));
            octetSecond = current.substring(0,7-(i)%8); 
        }
        else
        {
            octetSecond = current.substring(0,7-(i)%8);
        }   
    }
}

//var data =  DATA_ENCODING + VALID_PERIOD + userDataSize;

var PDU =   output;

return  PDU;
      }

    <input onclick="pduOut.value= stringToPDU(document.stringToPduForm.smsText.value.substring (0, maxkeys),document.stringToPduForm.size);" type="button" size="11" value="  Convert  " name="stringButton">
```

I need to know what changes needed so that the formula can encode message with 1-bit padding..but I not really understand the concept,can someone teach me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write out those octets in binary (with the lowest bit first in each octet) and you'll see it:

```
E8 32 9B FD 06 DD DF 72 36 19 = 00010111 01001100 11011001 10111111 01100000 10111011 11111011 01001110 01101100 10011000
D0 65 36 FB 0D BA BF E5 6C 32 = 00001011 10100110 01101100 11011111 10110000 01011101 11111101 10100111 00110110 01001100
```

Comment: Ohhh, I see it. Thank you so much Ilmari , I understand it now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

The overall encoding formula is the same.

What you are talking about is adding some number of bits (in this case 1 bit) of padding on the start of the user data so that the user data starts on both an octet and a septet boundary.

This is used for multi-part SMS where the user data header contains (octet-based) information about how to re-assemble the parts into one message. Some receiving devices might not be able to interpret the UDH so by ensuring that the subsequent data starts on both an octet boundary and a septet boundary, those devices will show garbage on the front of the message but will at least decode the message text correctly.

You'll find it helps to think of the user data as a bitstream rather than as octets or septets. You can then interpret it as either hex octets (as in your example at the top of the question) or as packed GSM septets for decoding. In fact, if you look at your two examples at the top of the question and write them out as binary bitstreams, you'll easily spot the relationship.

Comment: Not really understand but still thankyou(I'm very new in binary) . I tried to +1 in the formula but just 2 or 3 bits are not same.

Comment: And yes I understand that it's use to send multi-part sms , that's why I need it.